# Dynamically looping through controls has no effect

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a GUI class. I pass a frmMain (form) to GUI contructor. Then I have the following method to access child controls:

```
public void assignEvents(frmMain frm)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in frm.Controls)
    {
        ctl.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
        Log.AddData(ctl.Name.ToString() + ".Backcolor = " + ctl.BackColor.ToString(), 3);
    }
}
```

I get the new updated color in the output (log), but it takes no effect on controls and they are still in default color. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I call it like this:

```
    // GUI.cs
    public class GUI {
         public GUI(frmMain frm){
             assignEvents(frm);
         }
    }

    // frmMain.cs
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gui  = new M.Gui (this);
    }
```

Comment: you may need to redraw form - `frm.Invalidate()` after the foreach

Comment: You should *not* have to call `Invalidate()` after doing this, if the controls are written properly. I tested this by creating a form, dropping a button, a label and TextBox on it and adding a button handler that does the code above. It works fine when U click the button - the background colours change to GreenYellow.

Comment: No need for Invalidate(), the BackColor property setter already does that.  Add this line at the end of the method to see the changes: `frm.Show();`  Winforms is where a lot of programmers first learn about objected oriented programming.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: How are you calling `assignEvents()`? Is the form already visible when you call it?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I call it from form constructor.

Comment: We don't see you calling `assignEvents(...);`

Comment: @LarsTech sorry, I call the assignEvents from GUI constructor

Comment: Problem is somewhere else since the code you posted works.

Comment: @LarsTech The code works if I loop through items in usercontrol and updates controls fine, but not through subitems in usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you need to try to go recursively through each ControlCollection to set the BackColor property.

Try changing your code to something like this:

```
public GUI(frmMain frm) {
  assignEvents(frm.Controls);
}

public void assignEvents(Control.ControlCollection controls) {
  foreach (Control ctl in controls) {
    ctl.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;
    assignEvents(ctl.Controls);
  }
}
```